# Linear hull of meager convex set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $S\subset X$ be meager and convex.

> Is the linear hull of $S$ still meager?

Comment: Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $S = \{1\}$.

Comment: For any Banach space $X$, take a continuous linear functional  $f$ and set $S=f^{-1}(1)$.